# Python decode utf

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, decode, encode

having a brain fart.  But how do i decode a string that contains.

```
t = '%2Fdata%2F'
print(t.decode('utf8'))
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

expecting `/data/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2F` is a hexadecimal number of `/` character. Python has [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) function that returns a character representation by a **decimal** number.

So you need to get two symbols after `%`s and "decode" ("hex" -> `chr(`[`int("hex",16)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)`)`) them into a character.

```
def decode_utf(string):
    for i in range(string.count("%")):
        tmp_index = string.index("%")
        hex_chr = string[tmp_index:tmp_index + 3]
        #replace only one characher at a time
        string = string.replace(hex_chr, chr(int(hex_chr[1:],16)),1)
    return string

print(decode_utf("%2Fdata%2F"))
#/data/
print(decode_utf("hello%20world%21"))
#hello world!
```

---

**Edit 1:**

The previous code breaks if there's `%25` character, use the code below.

```
def decode_utf(string):
    utf_characters = []
    tmp_index = 0

    for i in range(string.count("%")):
        tmp_index = string.index("%",tmp_index)
        hex_chr = string[tmp_index:tmp_index + 3]
        if not hex_chr in utf_characters:
            utf_characters.append(hex_chr)

        tmp_index += 1

    for hex_chr in utf_characters:
        string = string.replace(hex_chr, chr(int(hex_chr[1:],16)))

    return string

print(decode_utf("%25t%20e%21s%2ft%25"))
#%t e!s/t%
```

Comment: This is a nice programming exercise. But in real code there's no need to re-invent the wheel – just use the standard library: `from urllib.parse import unquote; unquote('%2Fdata%2F')` → returns "/data/".

Comment: Btw, your solution breaks for examples like this one: `"%25data%25"` – it should return `"%data%"`, but it actually produces `"Úta%25"`.

Comment: @lenz I wish I knew about this function a year ago. Thanks for the info. Program was returning incorrect output because it was trying to replace `%FF` symbol that was already replaced. I've fixed it.